# C++: reference wrappers and printf

Tags: c++, reference, printf, stdvector, reference-wrapper

I have a `std::vector` of `std::reference_wrapper` objects that I want to print with printf (without cout); now, if I write

```
int a=5;
std::reference_wrapper<int> b=a;
printf("%i\n\n",b);
```

I get a nosense number (I think is the address of `a`); to obtain my value I have to do

```
printf("%i\n\n",b.get());
```

Is there a way to have automatic call to `.get()` function in `printf` (e.g. a different `%` specificator that print me the `reference_wrapper content`) so I can make a generalized function that works both with `std::reference_wrapper<type>` and `type`?

Comment: The first step would be to use the iostream library rather than the stdio library.

Comment: Your first code snippet won't compile everywhere. `error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'class std::reference_wrapper<int>' through '...'`

Comment: @Hurkyl I already use iostream

Comment: @ChristianHackl I compile it without problems...try disabling warnings

Comment: @volperossa: Why would disabling warnings prevent an error? Why would I shut up the compiler which protests when you ask it to create an executable with undefined behaviour in it? Anyway, it produces this error with GCC 4.9.2, regardless of the warning level.

Comment: @volperossa: You're not using iostream in this code example: you're using stdio.

Comment: For the record, MSVC produces a diagnostic message as well: `warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%i' requires an argument of type 'int', but variadic argument 1 has type 'std::reference_wrapper<int>'`

Comment: @ChristianHackl "Why would disabling warnings prevent an error? Why would I shut up the compiler which protests when you ask it to create an executable with undefined behaviour in it?" just for testing and understanding the behavior :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to at least consider using a C++ IO library instead of legacy C functions. That being said, you can write a wrapper around `printf` to provide unwrapping of reference wrappers:

```
template<typename... Params>
void my_printf(char const* fmt, Params&&... ps)
{
    printf(fmt, unwrap(std::forward<Params>(ps))...);
}
```

with `unwrap` implemented as follows:

```
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) unwrap_impl(T&& t, std::false_type){
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}

template<typename T>
decltype(auto) unwrap_impl(T&& t, std::true_type){
    return t.get();
}

template<typename T>
decltype(auto) unwrap(T&& t)
{
    return unwrap_impl(std::forward<T>(t), is_reference_wrapper<std::decay_t<T>>{});
}
```

and the `is_reference_wrapper` trait:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_reference_wrapper : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_reference_wrapper<std::reference_wrapper<T>> : std::true_type{};
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5f23708f6085a7b)

Answer (score 2):

`printf()` is a C library function that knows absolutely nothing about C++ classes and references, and will never know anything about them.

C++ has its own input/output library, that uses stream objects, that knows about C++ classes, and how to use them:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <memory>

int main()
{
    int a=5;
    std::reference_wrapper<int> b=a;

    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5
```

Answer (score 1):

`printf` doesn't do implicit type conversion, at least not calling the conversion operator in this case for your std::reference_wrapper, to make it work you need to use something that can do type conversion, like `std::cout`.

```
#include <iostream>                                                             

int a=5;                                                                        
std::reference_wrapper<int> b=a;                                                

int main() {                                                                                                                           
    std::cout<<b<<std::endl;                                                    
}
```